# Error 400 Bad Request Ajax Sending SMTP Email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I've been stuck on this issue for a few weeks now. I'm trying to send a SMTP email using form data provided while staying on the same page.

I've followed many examples online, but can't seem to Frankenstein it all together to make it work for me. I believe that the issue is with getting the data from the form.

**HTML**

```
<div id="form-messages"></div>
          <form method="post" action="" id="main-contact-form" >
            <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn-submit">
            </div>
          </form>
```

**JQuery/Ajax**

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/adb2/mailer.php",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will contact you as soon as possible!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**PHP (mailer.php)**

```
    <?php
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

         // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        require("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // SMTP password

        $mail->From = $email;

        $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxxx", "Website");

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->AltBody = $message;

        // Send the email.
        if ($mail->Send()) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
?>
```

After submitting the form, it returns "POST http://localhost:8080/adb2/mailer.php 400 (Bad Request)"

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Thank you for reading!

Comment: Since it's your code that's setting the 400 response, you need to check which of your conditions is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Synchro, I got it working now after passing in "data" in the ajax braces.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some more digging. I added a variable named "formData" and serialized the form. After that I passed it into the ajax call and it is working now. Below is the fixed JQuery/Ajax.

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/adb2/mailer.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );

        }
    }).done(function(response){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will contact you as soon as possible!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#subject').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    }).fail(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');
    });
});
```